# Find a list of strings across a data table in R

Tags: r, string, search, data.table

I have a vector of strings (candidates), each of which I want to find within a data table (FBgn_Dmels), and return the first column entry if a match is found within a row (e.g. CG2175 should return "1-Dec").

```
> head(candidates)
[1] "CG2175" "CG31196"  "CG3169"  "CG15168" "CG2252"  "CG2019" 

> FBgn_Dmels
               V1_01       V1_02       V1_03       V1_04       V1_05       V1_06       V1_07       V1_08       V1_09   V1_10 V1_11 V1_12 V1_13 V1_14
    1:         1-Dec FBgn0000427 FBgn0000645      CG2175          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    2:         1-Sep FBgn0011710 FBgn0005665 FBgn0013404 FBgn0014082 FBgn0024226      CG1403          NA          NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    3:         128up FBgn0010339 FBgn0010196      CG8340          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
    4: 14-3-3epsilon FBgn0020238 FBgn0011329 FBgn0016739 FBgn0016743 FBgn0046456 FBgn0051196 FBgn0064146 FBgn0066007 CG31196    NA    NA    NA    NA
    5:    14-3-3zeta FBgn0004907 FBgn0010635 FBgn0019723 FBgn0023038 FBgn0046306 FBgn0064146     CG17870          NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
   ---                                                                                                                                              
17743:          Zw10 FBgn0004643 FBgn0000016 FBgn0002765 FBgn0029627      CG9900          NA          NA          NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
17744:        Zwilch FBgn0061476 FBgn0036933 FBgn0042214     CG18729     CG18639          NA          NA          NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
17745:           zyd FBgn0265767 FBgn0243503 FBgn0025689 FBgn0058147 FBgn0040030      CG2893     CG40147          NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
17746:           zye FBgn0036985      CG5847          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
17747:           Zyx FBgn0011642 FBgn0047225 FBgn0052018     CG32018          NA          NA          NA          NA      NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

I could solve the issue using loops over a data frame, but it seems quite slow and inefficient. I was wondering if there is a straightforward way of doing this with data tables.

Many thanks in advance for suggestions how tackle this.

-Geo

Comment: Can you please add the result from `dput(head(FBgn_Dmels))` and also show your desired result

Comment: Sure! [dput.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4O_1QJrsxX6QUQtVDItS1NWaHc/view?usp=sharing). A match should return the entry in the first column as table or list.

Comment: e.g. "1-Dec";"CG2175"   "zye";"CG5847"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty hacky, but seems to work. I'm assuming your data is called FBgn_Dmels:

```
candidates <- c("CG2175", "CG31196", "CG3169", "CG15168", "CG2252", "CG2019")
getthem <- function(string){
  string <- paste0("^",string,"$")
  as.character(FBgn_Dmels[which(apply(FBgn_Dmels, 2, function(x) grepl(string, x, perl=TRUE)), arr.ind = TRUE)[1], "V1_01"][1])
}
```

sapply(candidates, getthem)

First we have defined a function (`getthem`) which gets the first occurrence for a single one, then we use `sapply` to hit all the candidates.

Comment: I had to set 'j' to the column name in order to display the value of the first column: (`as.character(FBgn_Dmels[which(apply(FBgn_Dmels, 2, function(x) grepl(string, x, fixed=TRUE)), arr.ind = TRUE)[1], V1_01][1])` . Only remaining issue is that it does not return exact matches only (this code matches CG3196 to CG31960 despite `fixed=TRUE`)

Comment: ok try it now : I've changed the string to be ^string$ (the ^ and $ are start and end, so it shouldnt match others)